# Adding a constraint requiring a number to fall between an upper and lower bound (ortools Constraint Optimization / CP)

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools

Crux of the question: "Any ideas on how to most appropriately code this constraint in ortools for a CP model?"

---

The problem I am trying to solve is a bit like the employee scheduling one outlined here:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling

Problem

I want to build a classroom assignment schedule that assigns students to classrooms each day over a period of time (right now, weekly for the next 2 years).

I have a school with 8 classrooms. Students are assigned to a classroom depending on their age. Each classroom has an age range associated with it - e.g.:

- Class 1: 1-3 years old
- Class 2: 2-4 years old
- Class 3: 3-5 years old,
  etc.

Notice, the classrooms do overlap in age ranges.

Students should be assigned to classrooms with the following constraints:

- 1) Each student must be assigned to exactly 1 classroom each day
- 2) The sum of students in a classroom must not exceed the maximum capacity for students in that classroom
- 3) Each student must be assigned to a classroom appropriate for their age
- 4) Once a student moves to a higher classroom (e.g., from class 2 to class 3), they may not move back down to a lower classroom

Here are my data:

**Students** = list of lists; each lists contains information about 1 student:
(e.g.,

`students = [['Student ID', 'Date of Birth', 'classroom_index'], ...]`

where:

- 'Student ID' = unique id for each student
- 'Date of Birth' = date object, and
- 'classroom_index' = student's current classroom assignment (1, 2, 3, etc.)

**Classrooms** = list of lists; each lists contains information about 1 classroom: (e.g.,

`classrooms = [['classroom_index', 'ageMin', 'ageMax', 'capacity']...]`

where:

- 'classroom_index' = unique id for each classroom (i.e.., 1-8),
- 'ageMin' = minimum age bound for the classroom (integer in years)
- 'ageMax' = maximum age bound for the classroom (integer in years), and
- 'capacity' = maximum number of students that may be assigned to a classroom on any given day

**Dates** = list of dates covering the period of the forecast schedule; in this case, the forecast schedule accounts for every Monday over the next 2 years:

`dates = [2019/11/25, 2019/12/2, ...]`

Current Status:

Following the structure of the employee scheduling code linked above, this is what I have:

### Declare the model

```
model = cp_model.CpModel()
```

### Create the variables

```
classroom_assignments = {}

for i, d in enumerate(dates):
  for s in students:
    for c in classrooms:
      classroom_assignments[(i, s[0], c[0])] = model.NewBoolVar('classroom_assignments_i%is%ic%i' % (i, s[0], c[0]))
```

### Assign students to classrooms

```
## The sum of students assigned to a classroom each day must be <= the capacity of that classroom
for i, d in enumerate(dates):
  for c in classrooms:
    model.Add(sum(classroom_assignments[(i, s[0], c[0])] for s in students) <= c[3])

## The sum of classrooms that a student is assigned to each day must be exactly 1
for s in students:
  for i, d in enumerate(dates):
    model.Add(sum(classroom_assignments[(i, s[0], c[0])] for c in classrooms) == 1)

## The sum of classrooms that a student is assigned to each day where the student's age is outside the min/max range for the classroom must be exactly 0
for s in students:
  for i, d in enumerate(dates):
    d_diff = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(d, s[1])
    age = (d_diff.years * 12)
    model.Add(sum(classroom_assignments[(d, s[0], c[0])] for c in classrooms) == 1 if c[1] <= age and c[2] >= age)
```

The last `for` loop above is my attempt to define constraint #3, it throws and error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-65-205499abc4dd>", line 15
    model.Add(sum(classroom_assignments[(d, s[0], c[0])] for c in classrooms) == 1 if c[1] <= age_months and c[2] >= age_months)
                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on how to most appropriately code this constraint in ortools for a CP model?

I tried to provide as much information as is relevant, but please let me know if you require additional information or clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple syntax error, the filter for your comprehension is in the wrong scope.

```py
model.Add(
    sum(
        classroom_assignments[(d, s[0], c[0])]
        for c in classrooms
        if c[1] <= age_months and c[2] >= age_months
    )
    == 1
)
```

Comment: That certainly fixes the error. Now, I'll need to determine if this syntax, is in fact, correctly applying the constraint as I intend. Appreciate the quick turn help.

Comment: Certainly, as I didn't check if the modeling is correct